# Decompile a Fortran .dll file

Tags: fortran, decompiler

I'm working with TRNSYS which uses Fortran for programming (which I don't really know a lot about).
I had a file (.f90) with my code, now it's empty. It is compiled in a .dll file.

Is there a way to decompile it, so that I can roughly see, what I had coded? It does not need to restore the file, so I can run it. I just kind of need to know, what's in it. It is not that much code, but I can't remember everything. I have a backup from beginning of Dec., which has the main structure but is obviously not the latest version.

I'd be glad for any help, thanks in advance
Jan

I have tried using Reko Decompiler, but I can't really make sense of the output.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran]. Fortran 90 is just one very old revision of the standard and the description of the tag says you should not use this tag alone.

Comment: You can disassemble the code to see the machine instructions, but frankly, it will most likely be useless to you and it is what you see with the decompiler you tried. Use git or mercurial for your future work. Take this as a lesson that these tools are not optional. For small programs and scripts use at least some directory that is shared in some cloud service. Even owncloud stores some older versions.